# How to make all variables not required in json serializable

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serialization

In json_serialization when i use the annotation @JsonKey(required: false), i am able to make a variable nullable, but then i have to annote all variables with this, it there a way to make this this general for a class, so all the variables can be nullable?

example

[image]

is there a way to generalize this?

Comment: Please always add any code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is the [includeIfNull property](https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonSerializable/includeIfNull.html) of the `@JsonSerializable` annotation:

```js
@JsonSerializable(includeIfNull: true)
class MyClass {
...
}
```

This makes all fields nullable by default and includes fields with null values in the serialized output.

*Edit*: You will still need to mark the variables as nullable using the question mark, e.g.:

```js
final String? sender;
```

Comment: one more thing, do i still need to make variable type nullable example
String? id;
@ada

Comment: Yes, you still need to make them nullable by including the question mark.

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues here.
Never heard about that **json_serialization** package, and couldn't find it in **pub.dev**. 
You can create Dart objects based on data read from a **JSON**, but you can't have `NULL` properties.

All properties of a Dart class should be immediately initialized or have a **late** reference when you give them a value when the `initState()` is called.

And a kind reminder that JSON doesn't require a fixed data format, however, you can force it to always have the required properties, if you control both services that create and read JSON.

If you use a third-party API or service, you must ensure that the properties exist before using them, and instead of storing every property on a Dart class, you can use a `Map<String, Dynamic>` to store the JSON content.

If you really need to have a Dart class to store the values, you should initialize all the String parameters as empty, instead of `NULL`.